# How to mutate a ndb repeated property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The appengine docu says on repeated ndb properiertes, that:

> When updating a repeated property, you can either assign it a new list
>   or mutate the existing list in place.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated

Two questions:

1. do I save write operations when I just mutate the list, instead of putting a new list in place?
2. how do I do exactly the mutation? just append the object and delete items within the list as I would do it with a list in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes you have it correct in your mind.

1. No you don't save because it's still a write operations with the applied costs.
2. Yes exactly like that. Appending like a normal list, deleting, etc etc.